# php Closure object how to read it?

Tags: php, closures

I have this code but I am stuck...

```
$my_var = function (){

  return array('hello you');
};

var_dump($my_var); // returns object(Closure)#2 (0) { }
```

how do I `echo $my_var`?

I would assume it would be `echo $my_var[0]`; but this does not work.

`Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Closure as array in ...`

Comment: Someone at PHP headquarters should be keelhauled for that error message. It demonstrates a dramatic lack of understanding of closure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A closure is a function. 
Therefore you have to call it, like this :

```
$myvar();
```

Since php5.4 with Array Access:

```
 echo   $myvar()[0];
```

Comment: yes, thank you, just was being stupid :) btw, `$myvar()[0]` I have read that will be available on php I can't remember which version, but I defenetly like the future for PHP.

Answer (score 1):

$my_var represents a function. You need to call it first to get the return value.

Answer (score -1):

try print_r it will print array or object

```
print_r($my_var);
```